# How to get all chart options from a google chart into a js variable?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

How can I get all of a google chart's options (chart  type, colors, legend, title...etc...) into a js variable so that I can use the same options to build another chart? The original chart is already build in a wrapper in a div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have a ChartWrapper object you can use the getOptions() method as described in the official doc [ChartWrapper Class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#methods_4).

If you can always use th ChartWrapper caus e ig gives you lot's of helpers that you can use to manipulate your chart data and options. [Here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/drawing_charts#chartwrapper) is the official doc

hope this helps

**UPDATE**

little sample from the doc actually I figured out that you probably need something else and that the toJSON() method is better

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current');   // Don't need to specify chart libraries!
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

      function drawVisualization() {
        var wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
          chartType: 'ColumnChart',
          dataTable: [['', 'Germany', 'USA', 'Brazil', 'Canada', 'France', 'RU'],
                      ['', 700, 300, 400, 500, 600, 800]],
          options: {'title': 'Countries'},
          containerId: 'vis_div'
        });
        wrapper.draw();
        console.log(wrapper.toJSON());

      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">

    <div id="vis_div" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

as you can see I added a console.log that calls the method.

You can play arround in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rixlabs/vjyagqrm/2/) if you need to do more experiments

**UPDATE 2**
I'm little slow understanding the problem :)

so if you need to have a second chart with the option of the frst the best idea is to clone(there is a clone() method for wrapper) the first wrapper and than change the attributes that you need to change

from the previous code, let's take the drawVisualization() method and update it for cloning:

```
 function drawVisualization() {
    var wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      chartType: 'ColumnChart',
      dataTable: [['', 'Germany', 'USA', 'Brazil', 'Canada', 'France', 'RU'],
                  ['', 700, 300, 400, 500, 600, 800]],
      options: {'title': 'Countries'},
      containerId: 'chart_div'
    });
    wrapper.draw();
    console.log(wrapper.toJSON());
    //hre you clone the wrapper
    wrapperCLone = wrapper.clone();
    console.log(wrapperCLone);
    //now you can change the data and some option and draw a new one
    wrapperCLone.setContainerId("second_chart_div");
    wrapperCLone.setDataTable([['', 'Germany', 'USA', 'Brazil', 'Canada', 'France', 'RU'],
                  ['', 1700, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1800]]);
    wrapperCLone.draw();

  }
```

as you can see we clone the wrapper in a new object wrapperCLone and than we set the new container ID and dataTable.

You can change all the single attribute of the wrapper, you can find the methods in the first guide I linked about the chartWrapper class.

I also updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vjyagqrm/3/) so you can see the 1th chart and below you can find the cloned one with different data table but same options.

Hope this is what you're looking for. good luck! :)

Comment: ChartWrapper is probably the easiest way to keep your options, chart type, and data together. Charts without a wrapper don't really "have" options so much as they are given them every time you draw. ChartWrappers don't need to have the options passed to them every draw, they always hold onto them for later. I think what the question is really asking is about the scoping of javascript variables.

Comment: @nbering we met again here :)

Comment: @rick Thank you. I knew I saw that somewhere but couldn't remember what and where. I'm still a beginner.... could you please use the getOptions() method in an example ... just one line, just a variable  = getOptions ... so that I can see the syntax...

Comment: updated the answere I figured out getOptions is not the right method try toJSON on wrapper as described in the UPDATED answere. hope this helps

Comment: @rick Thanks a million. ... however I am still unclear on how to utilize the toJSON() method to build a 2nd chart. what I need is to build a 2nd chart using the 1st one's options. Rick, I know very well I am being a dumbass but if you could help me out that would just make this moth for me a whole lot easier :)

Comment: wait my bad if you need a new chart with the first one optione there is a better way. Give me a second and I update the fiddle

Comment: @rick, thank you , thank you, THANK YOU. You gave me all I needed and a little more for the future. You wrote " I'm little slow understanding the problem"... that's because this is a part of a very big tool I am working on and it would be very difficult for me to explain everything form the ground up. But you have just solved my problem perfectly. Thank you